# Discovering public IP programmatically

Tags: python, ip-address, tcp

I'm behind a router, I need a simple command to discover my public ip (instead of googling what's my ip and clicking one the results)

Are there any standard protocols for this? I've heard about STUN but I don't know how can I use it?

P.S. I'm planning on writing a short python script to do it

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097589/getting-my-public-ip-via-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: curlmyip.com is no longer available. (thanks maxywb)

**Original Post**:

As of writing this post, curlmyip.com works. From the command line:

```
curl curlmyip.com
```

It's a third-party website, which may or may not be available a couple years down the road. But for the time being, it seems pretty simple and to the point.

Comment: yet another service: `curl icanhazip.com`

Comment: Another is mypubip.com which displays a three line text response when using curl.

Comment: 9 years and counting for https://api.ident.me :)

Answer (score 24):

This may be the easiest way. Parse the output of the following commands:

1. run a traceroute to find a router that is less than 3 hops out from your machine.
2. run ping with the option to record the source route and parse the output. The first IP address in the recorded route is your public one.

For example, I am on a Windows machine, but the same idea should work from unix too.

```
> tracert -d www.yahoo.com

Tracing route to www-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com [69.147.76.15]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.14.203
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     8 ms     8 ms     9 ms  68.85.228.121
  4     8 ms     8 ms     9 ms  68.86.165.234
  5    10 ms     9 ms     9 ms  68.86.165.237
  6    11 ms    10 ms    10 ms  68.86.165.242
```

The 68.85.228.121 is a Comcast (my provider) router. We can ping that:

```
> ping -r 9 68.85.228.121 -n 1

Pinging 68.85.228.121 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 68.85.228.121: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=253
    Route: 66.176.38.51 ->
           68.85.228.121 ->
           68.85.228.121 ->
           192.168.14.203
```

Voila! The 66.176.38.51 is my public IP.

**Python code to do this** (hopefully works for py2 or py3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def natIpAddr():
  # Find next visible host out from us to the internet
  hostList = []
  resp, rc = execute("tracert -w 100 -h 3 -d 8.8.8.8") # Remove '-w 100 -h d' if this fails

  for ln in resp.split('\n'):
    if len(ln)>0 and ln[-1]=='\r': ln = ln[:-1]  # Remove trailing CR
    if len(ln)==0: continue
    tok = ln.strip().split(' ')[-1].split('.') # Does last token look like a dotted IP address?
    if len(tok)!=4: continue
    hostList.append('.'.join(tok))
    if len(hostList)>1: break  # If we found a second host, bail
    
  if len(hostList)<2:
    print("!!tracert didn't work, try removing '-w 100 -h 3' options")
    # Those options were to speed up tracert results

  else:
    resp, rc = execute("ping -r 9 "+hostList[1]+" -n 1")
    ii = resp.find("Route: ")
    if ii>0: return resp[ii+7:].split(' ')[0]
  return none     


def execute(cmd, showErr=True, returnStr=True):
  import subprocess
  if type(cmd)==str:
    cmd = cmd.split(' ')
  # Remove ' ' tokens caused by multiple spaces in str             
  cmd = [xx for xx in cmd if xx!='']
  proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = proc.communicate()
  if type(out)==bytes:  # Needed for python 3 (stupid python)
    out = out.decode()
    try:
      err = err.decode()
    except Exception as ex: 
      err = "!!--"+str(type(ex))+"--!!"
  
  if showErr and len(err)>0:
    out += err
  if returnStr and str(type(out))=="<type 'unicode'>":
    # Trying to make 'out' be an ASCII string whether in py2 or py3, sigh.
    out = out.encode()  # Convert UNICODE (u'xxx') to string
  return out, proc.returncode


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("(This could take 30 sec)")
  print(natIpAddr())
```

Use it from the command line (on Windows) or from a python program:

```
import natIpAddr
myip = natIpAddr.natIpAddr()
print(myip)
```

Comment: +1: maybe not the easiest way, but it's neat to see a way that doesn't rely on some website.

Comment: But note that "Many hosts ignore or discard the RECORD_ROUTE option." See man ping.

Comment: This is the real answer. The other's all require some 3rd party website to stay alive.

Comment: This relies on ICMP messaging, which is often blocked. So this method is unreliable (and slow).

Comment: This answer has many flaws. The assumption that your traffic get's past all NAT gateways in 3 or less hops might work for many but is farm form certain.  A lot of servers don't respond to ICMP and even those that do may completely ignore the `RECORD_ROUTE` option (see https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping).

Answer (score 17):

I have made a program that connects to http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp
it is is written in D an getting someone else to tell you what they see your ip as is probably the most reliable way:

```
/*
    Get my IP address
*/


import tango.net.http.HttpGet;
import tango.io.Stdout;

void main()
{
      try
      {
          auto page = new HttpGet ("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp");
          Stdout(cast(char[])page.read);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          Stdout("An exception occurred");
      }
}
```

Edit python code should be like:

```
from urllib import urlopen
print urlopen('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp').read()
```

Comment: hehe I like ur name dude! (btw I love D)

Comment: The URL has been updated to http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp; see http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp for rules.

Comment: they also ask you to add a Mozilla user agent per the faq -- posted a verison that does so at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452952/find-my-ip-address-in-python/10750359#10750359 (wrapping with an except is a good idea if you're going to rely on this other code) -- https://gist.github.com/2786450

Answer (score 14):

I like the [ipify.org](https://ipify.org):

- it's free to use (even programmatically and allows even heavy traffic)
- the response contains only the IP address without any garbage (no need for parsing)
- you can also request a response in JSON
- works for both IPv4 and IPv6
- it's hosted in a cloud
- it's open-source

```
$ curl api.ipify.org
167.220.196.42

$ curl "api.ipify.org?format=json"
{"ip":"167.220.196.42"}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. If you suspect some web is not working, try some service like http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ipify.org first.

Answer (score 11):

Targeting www.whatsmyip.org is rude. They plea not to do that on the page.

Only a system on the same level of NAT as your target will see the same IP.
For instance, your application may be behind multiple layers of NAT (this happens more as you move away from the US, where the glut of IPs are).

STUN is indeed the best method. 
In general, you should be planning to run a (STUN) server somewhere that you 
application can ask: do not hard code other people's servers.  You have to code 
to send some specific messages as described in rfc5389.

I suggest a good read of, and related links.
http://www.ietf.org/html.charters/behave-charter.html

You may prefer to look at IPv6, and Teredo to make sure that you always have IPv6 access.
(Microsoft Vista makes this very easy, I'm told)

Comment: It seems that whatsmyip don't mind automated lookups so long as you follow some rules: http://forum.whatismyip.com/f14/  . If you break the rules than you can be banned.

Comment: the site ryeguy suggested is different .. what*is* .. not what*s* .. mykp.org

Comment: I see no such pleas on whatismyip.org .  What page are you speaking of?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by several people, [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) is indeed the proper solution.

- a list of [public STUN servers](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki-STUN)
- a free software [STUN client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/)
- The [STUN standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5389.txt)

Here's a code example using [`pynat` Python module](https://github.com/arantonitis/pynat):

```python
>>> import pynat
>>> pynat.get_ip_info()
('UDP Firewall', '192.0.2.2', 54320)
```

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I wanted to do this, I would just scrape [whatismyip.org](http://whatismyip.org). When you go to the site, it gives you your plain text public IP. Plain and simple.

Just have your script access that site and read the IP.

I don't know if you were implying this in your post or not, but it isn't possible to get your public IP from your own computer. It has to come from an external source.

**2013 edit: This site returns an image now instead of text, so it's useless for this purpose.**

Comment: nice! I didn't know about this site! usually google turns up a bunch of sites each of which is big and fat, probably with a note saying don't use automated tools! but this is awesome! thanks

Comment: It makes your program depend on an external site you do not control (same thing with STUN, of course, unless you run your own STUN server)...

Comment: Iwhatismyip.org seems completely broken: I get the answer 192.168.2.1 which is clearly not my public IP...

Comment: If you're developing an application and it somehow needs to know the local IP, then you're likely doing something wrong.  Don't make dependencies on local IP addrs, as they can change at any time (i.e. DHCP).   What's wrong with just using the NAT'd address?

Comment: STUN is the right way to do this.  Scraping whatismyip.org makes your application dependent on that service it isn't playing nice.

Comment: After looking at the site, it looks like the IP address is actually an imange generated with PHP. Wouldn't this be hard to parse?

Comment: @Glen: At the time of this answer, it just returned a plain text no-frills response.

Comment: @ryeguy Good point, but I was saying as of now, the site generates an image.

Comment: Read the image with Tesseract-OCR.  LOL

Answer (score 3):

Your simplest way may be to ask some server on the outside of your network.

One thing to keep in mind is that different destinations may see a different address for you. The router may be multihomed. And really that's just where problems begin.

Comment: Ditto if your ISP is doing any proxying

Comment: Completely false: there is a standard protocol, STUN, RFC 5389.

Comment: Interesting - wasn't familiar with that RFC. Is it widely implemented yet?

Comment: Good question, but I am not aware of any survey. Anyway, you do not need every machine on the Internet to implement it. If you develop a network program, just put STUN code in *your* program and set up a few public STUN servers (or see if the existing ones can be used).

Answer (score 3):

If the network has an UpNp server running on the gateway you are able to talk to the gateway and ask it for your outside IP address.

Answer (score 3):

To get your external ip, you could make a dns query to an opendns server with the special hostname "myip.opendns.com":

```
from subprocess import check_output

ip = check_output(["dig", "+short", "@resolver1.opendns.com",
                   "myip.opendns.com"]).decode().strip()
```

On Windows, you could try `nslookup`.

There is no dns module in Python stdlib that would allow to specify custom dns server. You could use third party libraries e.g., [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) to make the dns query:

```
from twisted.internet     import task # $ pip install twisted
from twisted.names.client import Resolver
from twisted.python.util  import println

def main(reactor):
    opendns_resolvers = [("208.67.222.222", 53), ("208.67.220.220", 53)]
    resolver = Resolver(servers=opendns_resolvers, reactor=reactor)
    # use magical hostname to get our public ip
    return resolver.getHostByName('myip.opendns.com').addCallback(println)
task.react(main)
```

Here's the same using [`dnspython` library](http://www.dnspython.org/):

```
import dns.resolver # $ pip install dnspython

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
resolver.nameservers = ["208.67.222.222", "208.67.220.220"]
print(resolver.query('myip.opendns.com')[0])
```

Here's `asyncio` variant using [`aiodns` library](https://github.com/saghul/aiodns):

```
$ pipenv install aiodns
$ pipenv run python -m asyncio
...
>>> import asyncio
>>> import aiodns  # pip install aiodns
>>> resolver = aiodns.DNSResolver()
>>> resolver.nameservers = "208.67.222.222", "208.67.220.220"
>>> await resolver.query("myip.opendns.com", "A")
[<ares_query_a_result> host=192.0.2.2, ttl=0]
```

To get IPv6 address:

```
>>> resolver.nameservers = "2620:119:35::35", "2620:119:53::53"
>>> await resolver.query("myip.opendns.com", "AAAA")
```

Answer (score 1):

Duck Duck Go gives free access to their API according to their own page here:
https://duckduckgo.com/api

Here's the URL you hit if you want your IP address:
http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=my+ip&format=json

That returns a JSON object. The `Answer` attribute has a human readable string with your ip address in it. Example:

```
{
    ...
    "Answer": "Your IP address is ww.xx.yyy.zzz in <a href=\"http://open.mapquest.com/?q=aaaaa(bbbbb)\">aaaaa(bbbbb)</a>"
    ...
}
```

You could extract the ip address from that string by using `split()[4]`, if you think that it's a safe assumption that this string won't ever change or you're willing to need to periodically fix it.

Alternatively, if you want to have a more future proof method, you could loop over everything returned by `split()` and return the first item that is an ip address. See here for validating IP addresses:
[How to validate IP address in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319279/901641)

Comment: Hardly "programmatic", but I use DuckDuckGo too

Comment: @Nemo - What's not "programmatic" about it? I didn't give a full code example, but this seems like plenty that you could use it if you want to. Then again, I think some other answers that people have added since I wrote mine are better than mine is.

Answer (score 1):

`curl api.infoip.io` - full details

`curl api.infoip.io/ip` - just the ip address

`curl api.infoip.io/country` - just the country name

... and more of the same

you can view the docs at http://docs.ciokan.apiary.io/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing you my method of retrieving a server's public IP address without having to use external APIs (which is a security risk of course)

```
INTERFACE=`ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep 8.8.8.8 | cut -d' ' -f5`
HOSTIP=`ifconfig $INTERFACE | grep "inet " | awk -F'[: ]+' '{ print $4 }'`
```

Or in python if you prefer:

```
import subprocess
public_ip = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep 8.8.8.8 | cut -d' ' -f5` | grep \'inet \' | awk -F'[: ]+' '{ print $4 }'"], shell=True)
```

It works like this:

- determines the best interface to reach the google dns server
- greps public IP from the `ifconfig` entry for that interface

Comment: This just gives me my local IP, not my public one.

Comment: perhaps you're using some exotic linux with different ip route output

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu counts as "exotic"

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few public services that support IPv4 and IPv6:

- `curl http://icanhazip.com`
- `curl http://www.trackip.net/ip`
- `curl https://ipapi.co/ip`
- `curl http://api6.ipify.org`
- `curl http://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace`
- `curl http://checkip.dns.he.net`

The following seem to support only IPv4 at this time:

- `curl http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com`
- `curl http://checkip.dyndns.org`
- `curl http://ifconfig.me`
- `curl http://ip-api.com`
- `curl http://api.infoip.io/ip`

It's easy to make an HTTP call programmatically. So all should be relatively easy to use, and you can try multiple different URLs in case one fails.

Answer (score -1):

another cheeky way:
if your router has got the option to update it's web IP on [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/), you can get your own IP with something like:

```
IP=`resolveip -s myalias.dyndns-home.com`
```

Comment: Cheeky indeed: if you have a Dynamic DNS service you probably don't *need* to find your external IP address, just use the name instead! That's *exactly* what such services are for :P

Answer (score -2):

It's now quite cheap to host your own "serverless" API. All the major cloud providers have a service for this. For example, using Google Cloud Functions all it takes is:

```
exports.requestIP = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(req.ip)
}
```

This approach is probably more reliable than using the public services above and you can add a long random string to the function's name to keep it private.