# how can i find my ip address with python not local ip?

Tags: python, selenium, import, pip, installation

How can i find my ip address with python not local ip ?
I try with socket but it find local ip.I need to ethernet outer ip.That's my code but it find local ip

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print("Your Computer Name is:" + hostname)
print("Your Computer IP Address is:" + IPAddr)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a machine's external IP address with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311510/getting-a-machines-external-ip-address-with-python)

Comment: no it find local ip but i want to find like whatismyipaddress.com

Comment: there is plenty of example in stackoverflow including the one i provided, you can use the search toolbar, plased on top.

Comment: You can try http://ipinfo.io/ip

Comment: and another service [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me/ip)

Answer (score 5):

I used to have this problem and this was my solution:

you should install this package then:

```
import requests

...

public_ip = requests.get("http://wtfismyip.com/text").text

print(public_ip)
```

It's not possible to get the public IP using socket