# Python | Is there a way to get my IP address?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that gets the IP address that the program is running on, is there a way of getting an IP address without using an API of some sort?

Comment: Your public IP or your private IP?

Comment: you will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib

Answer (score 4):

For your private ip:

```py
import socket    
hostname = socket.gethostname()    
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)    
print("Your Computer IP Address is:" + IPAddr)
```

Python's `socket` module is a great module for "all those networking stuff", like getting IP address.

For public ip you'll need to use an external service. Read more about it: [Getting a machine's external IP address with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311510/getting-a-machines-external-ip-address-with-python)

For example you can use: https://pypi.org/project/publicip/ (didn't try it myself)

Comment: That gets my computer IP, I want to get like the IP address that if I google "What's my IP?" for example

Comment: That's your public ip, you can't get it without any service. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311510/getting-a-machines-external-ip-address-with-python

Comment: Yeah I see, it would be weird getting an IP without requesting something. I was wondering if it would be simple or so without requesting a site/api.

Comment: finds "127.0.1.1"; the IP stored in /etc/hosts correlated with my computer name (Linux Ubuntu). But I need  my LAN IP received from the local DNS.