# Getting my public IP via API

Tags: api, ip

Is there a public API from some big company to get my public ip from within a program?

I've found `http://ip-address.domaintools.com/myip.xml`, which is exactly what I want, but unfortunately it blocks Python's `urllib` as well as many other http libraries, unless you spoof user-agent (anything doing that can't be called an API at all).

The problem is that I need this data for some potentially open source library, so we have to play by the rules. I also know that I can just do smth like `print $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]`, but I don't want to server traffic to everyone using my library.

So, is there something like the URL above, but real API, that allows robots?

Comment: related: [Discovering public IP programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/613471/4279)

Comment: Duck Duck Go has a public method for determining your IP address. I've detailed it more here, since this question is closed and I can't add an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33743758/901641

Comment: https://www.ipify.org/ is an alternate service.

Comment: I suggest trying Ipregistry: https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout (disclaimer: I run the service).

Comment: https://api.ident.me welcomes robots :)

Comment: There are a few that return what you need, such as https://api.miip.co, https://api.myip.com, https://api.internet-protocol.com

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 102, accepted):

While not from big companies, all of these should work:

```
curl icanhazip.com
curl -s 'http://checkip.dyndns.org' | sed 's/.*Current IP Address: \([0-9\.]*\).*/\1/g'
host -t a dartsclink.com | sed 's/.*has address //'
curl curlmyip.com
curl ifconfig.me # this has a lot of different alternatives too, such as ifconfig.me/host
```

Source

- http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2966/return-external-ip#comment

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot, esp. for dyndns one, that'll do!

Comment: icanhazip.com returns the cleanest result imho

Comment: Also http://ipinfo.io/ip

Comment: @mnagel It also seems to be the only one that supports HTTPS. How ironic...

Comment: You may check https://www.ipify.org/, that have a clear API and does support HTTPS.

Comment: icanhazip.com is so far the only one I've encountered that is both IPv6 capable and ATS (TLSv1.2 & PFS) compliant. Now, if I can just find an API set like http://ipv6-test.com/api/ that allows forcing IPv4 or IPv6 and is ATS compliant, that would be terrific!

Comment: Nice, icanhazip.com supports IPv6.

Comment: @RyanH. how about https://api.ident.me? Provides IPv4 vs IPv6, supports HTTPS and TLSv1.2 (works in nscurl). Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 47):

You can get your IP, and a whole bunch of other information, from my service http://ipinfo.io:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "67.188.232.131",
  "hostname": "c-67-188-232-131.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.385999999999996,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",
  "phone": 650
}
```

If you want just the IP:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/ip
67.188.232.131
```

That also works for other fields, eg:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/org
AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.
```

More details available at http://ipinfo.io/developers

Comment: Does not support HTTPS

Comment: The paid plans all have HTTPS support. See http://ipinfo.io/pricing

Comment: No IPv6 support...

Comment: It supports IPv6 via v6.ipinfo.io

Comment: Looks like https is now supported, no paid plan required.

Answer (score 20):

In JSON format giving more details like the country and the user-agent:

https://www.trackip.net/ip?json

or only the IP

https://www.trackip.net/ip

for [pfsense](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/dns/ip-address-check-services.html) (Check IP Services):

http://trackip.net/pfsense

Comment: Nice. Also supports IPv6.

Comment: Supports https too. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

I use this one, easy to remember and it's shorter than others:

`$ curl ifconfig.me`

PROTIP: Remember that if you use curl in shell scripts you have to use `-s` option, otherwise it prints the download progress table.

`` $ echo `curl -s ifconfig.me` ``

Comment: I am moving from _ifconfig.me_ to _ipinfo.io_ due to slowness

Comment: No IPv6 support...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may try out with whoisthisip.com

http://whoisthisip.com/HRAS/
 Register to whoisthisip.com to get a website's IP address information such as city location, country location and domain name.

Once signed in, you will be given a reference code and a url to view and get the information of IP address for the website you registered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use web service API's which do this work like:

```
see example of service: http://ip-api.com and usage: http://whatmyip.info
```

good luck!!!

Comment: http://ip-api.com/json is fastest way and it has best response time. 150 requests/minute

Answer (score -1):

Access ip infomation using this api:

http://cms.javabrown.com/jws/ws.php?service=IpService

JSONP:

http://cms.javabrown.com/jws/ws.php?service=IpService&callback=?

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot install curl in your system wget variant would be:

```
wget -qO- curlmyip.com
```