# Find my Ip address in python

Tags: python, networking, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

How can I get my Ip address?

```
socket.gethostbyname( socket.gethostname() )
```

this is returning 127.0.1.1 but how can I get my real IP?