# python: check if IP or DNS

Tags: python, regex, dns, ip

how can one check if variable contains DNS name or IP address in python ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3462784/280730

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/q/319279/280730

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Comment: so many dupes, but no one closes it. :D

Comment: @N1.1 because they aren't exact duplicates. There are answers to this question that aren't Regex.  The question isn't asking about pattern matching in general either, it's asking about a specific one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module of Python to check if the contents of the variable is a ip address.

Example for the ip address :

```
import re

my_ip = "192.168.1.1"
is_valid = re.match("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", my_ip)

if is_valid:
    print "%s is a valid ip address" % my_ip
```

Example for a hostname :

```
import re

my_hostname = "testhostname"
is_valid = re.match("^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$", my_hostname)

if is_valid:
    print "%s is a valid hostname" % my_hostname
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319279/how-to-validate-ip-address-in-python/4017219#4017219

Comment: Awesome. both two regex would be helpful.

Answer (score 12):

This will work.

```
import socket
host = "localhost"
if socket.gethostbyname(host) == host:
    print "It's an IP"
else:
    print "It's a host name"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out the answer for this SO question:

[Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

The main point is to take those two regexs and OR them together to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'ip' if s.split('.')[-1].isdigit() else 'domain name'
```

This does not verify if either one is well-formed.