# Simple python assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

basically I need the user to enter an ip address.
All I need to do is check that it's valid (0-255; 4 octets).
lets say a user enters 192.168.10.1,
how can I break it down to 192, 168, 10, 1?

Comment: This can be solved via regular expressions.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: This can be solved trivially without regular expressions: `"192.168.0.1".split('.') == ['192', '168', '0', '1']`

Comment: Check out [How to check if a string matches an IP adress pattern in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3462784)

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should accept the answer that helped the most.  That gives a reward to the person who helped you and removes this question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
while True:
    ip = raw_input("Please enter an ip address")
    ip_split = ip.split(".")
    if len(ip_split) != 4:
        print "Must have 4 numbers"
    elif not all(number.isdigit() for number in ip_split):
        print "Must be numbers"
    elif not all(0 <= int(number) <= 255 for number in ip_split):
        print "Numbers must be in 0-255 range"
    else:
        ips = [int(number) for number in ip_split]
        break
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow "999.999.999.999", which is not legal?

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you for mentioning that.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method:

```
 your_string.split(separator)
```

In your case:

```
 ip = "191.168.10.1"
 values_list = ip.split(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this 2 regexes to check this

```
import re

ip4 = re.compile(r'^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|\d?\d)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|\d?\d)$')
ip6 = re.compile(r'^(?:[\da-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[\da-fA-F]{1,4}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways. This could be a solution:

```
ip = "192.168.10.666"
octates = ip.split('.',4)

flag = True
for each_octate in octates:
    num = int(each_octate)
    if num>=0 and num<=255:
        continue
    else:
        flag = False
        break

if flag == True:
    print "IP is correct!"
else:
    print "IP is incorrect"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take the ip address in as a string and then from there split the str by "." and then check each member for that criteria.

```
ip = input("Enter Ip address: ")
address = ip.split('.')
if len(address) == 4:
     for num in address:
          if 255 >= num >= 0:
               pass
          else:
               print("Invalid Ip Address!")
else:
     print("Invalid Ip Address!")
```