# Regular Expression for IP address separated by comma or *

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to build a RegEx that will match with a string of IPs separated by comma (`,`) OR string will have only `*`. String should not have both IP address & *

1. Validate IP i.e `1.1.1.1` (Numbers and `.` dot char). Also, `*` alone is allowed
2. `*` is present, no other IPs should be present.

This is the regex

```
(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(,\n|,?))|(,*))
```

Testing string:

```
192.168.1.1,192.56.3.23,189.35.2.2,198.23.45.56,198.168.1.255
```

How do I check for `*`?

Comment: It seems we need more than one string to test. Please supply some more valid and invalid strings. Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS6eE8/1) - is that something like what you need?

Comment: @punter why exactly do you think a regular expression is the best way to verify the data? Would it not be simpler to just split the string on `,` characters and verify that each IP address is valid, and then for each IP address, split on `.` characters and very that each number or `*` is valid? Sometimes writing more lines of code is better than trying to write a single very clever line of code.

Comment: Just check for `st == '*'`. As for IP addresses, regex is indeed not the best idea, there are some better methods described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3462840/5629218).

Comment: Maybe [this regex will help](https://regex101.com/r/nA9tQ7/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)|\*)(?:,\s*(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)|\*))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJ9A1Y/2)

[Expanded//verbose/free-spacing version](https://regex101.com/r/VJ9A1Y/1):

```
^         # start of string
 (?:      # start of a grouping
  (?:     # start of another grouping
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\. # First octet and .
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\. # Second octet and .
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\. # Third octet and .
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)   # Fourth octet
   |\*                               # or just a * char instead of an IP
  )                                  # end of another grouping
 )                                   # end of grouping
 (?:,\s*             # a group that will repeat 0+ times, matches , then 0+ whitespaces   
  (?:                # an IP matching grouping
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\. # First octet and .
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\. # Second octet and .
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\. # Third octet and .
   (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)   # Fourth octet
  |\*)                               # Or a *
 )*                                  # ... zero or more times 
$                                    # end of string
```