# Pandas Find if url contains IP address

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to return a boolean result for a column finding ip addresses in a url as `true` and no ip address in url as `false`

```
    col1
0   http://197.248.5.23/
1   https://197.248.5.23/
2   http://179.12.170.88/pdf/forced/jit/
3   http://tel:888
4   http://li
```

Desired output:

```
    col1                                   contains_ip
0   http://197.248.5.23/                   True
1   https://197.248.5.23/                  True
2   http://179.12.170.88/pdf/forced/jit/   True
3   http://tel:888                         False
4   http://li                              False
```

Comment: `df['col1'].str.contains('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')` inspired from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462784/check-if-a-string-matches-an-ip-address-pattern-in-python also check the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this regex:

```
df.col1.str.match('^(http|https)://\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.*')
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df["col1"].str.match(r"https?://(\d+\.){3}\d+/")
```