# How to turn string to int with with characters within it?

Tags: python

I'm building a simple email verifier and I need to know how to turn an ip address string into ints. I need (example Ip address) [a.b.c.d] to all be their own integer so that I may see if each is in the range of 0-255. The problem is that there are dots that separate them and I don't know how to just convert the individual sections.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `'1.2.3.4'.split('.')`.

Comment: I've never seen anyone use email addresses that are numeric ip addresses.  Well, I'll admit to using `root@127.0.0.1` on a few sites... to sign up for their spam.  Good filters will try to catch this sort of thing.

Comment: @Paul It's true that you never really see this but you still could do this, I considered this possibility before

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate IP address in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319279/how-to-validate-ip-address-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use the `split` method of string and judge every number is between [0,255]:

```
>>> a = '127.0.0.1'
>>> all(map(lambda a : 0 <= a <= 255, [int(i) for i in a.split('.')]))
True
>>> b = '256.1.2.3'
>>> all(map(lambda a : 0 <= a <= 255, [int(i) for i in b.split('.')]))
False
```

First use split() to get every part of an IP address and you get a list:

```
>>> a = '127.0.0.1'
>>> alist = a.split('.')
>>> alist
['127', '0', '0', '1']
```

Now, use list comprehension to get the number of of a alsit:

```
>>> num_list = [int(i) for i in alist]
>>> num_list
[127, 0, 0, 1]
```

I don't use try except the ValueError cause your input is IP, if not you can follow other answer.

Then, use map to judge if every number in num_list is in [0,255], it take an anonymous function and the list you want to judge. It return the bool value of every result of the element in num_list by judged the anonymous function:

```
>>> map(lambda num: 0 <= num <= 255, num_list)
[True, True, True, True]
```

Last, try all() function it will return True if all element in a list is True, otherwise False:

```
>>> all(map(lambda num: 0 <= num <= 255, num_list))
True
```

Comment: I believe this is what I need. Can you explain how each part of it works?

Comment: I really love you for this :) Thanks for the awesome explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

As Charles Duffy suggested in the comments, the string.split() method will split a string into several substrings, returning a list of all substrings.

If you want to split at each 'dot', then use string.split('.'), otherwise it will split at whitespace.

For example:

```
address = ['10.1.0.1']
address_split = address.split('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Building slightly on Andrew Guy's suggestion:

```
try:
    address_octets = [int(x) for x in address.split('.')]
except ValueError, e:
    pass
    # fallback from the assumption that it's an IPv4 string
    # (Whatever that means for your code)
assert len(address_octets) == 4
    # (or use a conditional and fallback as described above)
```

... note that I have no idea how you'll want to handle the parsing failures and I'm not entirely sure that the only exception you could get would be `ValueError`.