# regex for IPv4 matching

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to match IPv4 addresses using `regex`. I got following `regex`.

But I am not able to understand `?:` in it.

```
## r'(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'

>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)', txt)
['254.123.11.13', '254.123.11.14', '254.123.12.13', '254.123.12.14', '254.124.11.13', '254.124.11.14', '254.124.12.13']
```

I know `?:` is for avoiding capturing of a group, but here I am not able to make a sense with it.

**Update:**
If I am removing `?:`, I am getting following result. I thought I will get IP address along with captured groups in tuples.

```
>>> re.findall(r'((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)', txt)
[('11.', '11', '13'), ('11.', '11', '14'), ('12.', '12', '13'), ('12.', '12', '14'), ('11.', '11', '13'), ('11.', '11', '14'), ('12.', '12', '13')]
```

Comment: Why down vote for this question?

Comment: As you said none-capture group token is for avoiding capturing a group.and in this case its the whole aim of using it. i you don't use it in this case for each IP alongside  the whole of IP you'll get another extra parts.

Comment: Down vote is because you've answered to your question already!

Comment: @Kasra I added an *Update*. When I am removing `?:`, I am not getting IP address.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're particular about the regex or not, but another solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/319298/1695766

Comment: @mescalinum Nope. this is more of a question about the working of `?:` with `findall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-capture group is needed in this case because the {3} repeat specifier for your IPv4 quartet returns only the third match. The outer group however will provide all 3 of the matching inner matches: ( q{3} ) where q=regex for a number in your quartet. However we want to hide the third match with non-capture specifier for the inner group.

See below for a regex without the non-capturing, problem and a solution.

```
q = r'(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
```

Reproducing the {3} repeat problem without non-capturing:

```
t = '(%s\.){3}%s' % (q,q)
>>> re.findall(t,txt)
[('11.', '11', '13'), ('11.', '11', '14')]
```

Solution if you wanted tuples captured separately:

```
s='{0}\.{0}\.{0}\.{0}'.format(q)
>>> re.findall(s, txt)
[('254', '123', '11', '13'), ('254', '123', '11', '14')]
```

or

```
s='({0}\.{0}\.{0}\.{0})'.format(q)
>>> re.findall(s,txt)
[('254.123.11.13', '254', '123', '11', '13'), ('254.123.11.14', '254', '123', '11', '14')]
```

Answer (score 1):

As i said in comment if you don't use non-capture group instead of matching the whole of your regex and due to this note that you have 3 group in your regex you'll get 3 result for each IP.

For better demonstration see the following sate machine :

without non-capture group :

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/M5gncwjUkg5QpkFc)

Using non-capture group :

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iRyhoZF3PNCdQ8F3)

As you can see when you sue non-capturing group you have not any group and the whole of your regex will interpret as one group usually the group 0!