# Check if valid ip address from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, and would like help for my code below. I like to be able to verify if the end user has key in a valid IP address. I searched online, and all the examples are too complex to understand hence I'm asking.

If possible would like the code to also loop back if the person input a invalid value.

```
input = 61.1.1.1

wanip = str(input("please key in WAN IP address:"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate IP address in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319279/how-to-validate-ip-address-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ipaddress.html) module.

For example:

```
import ipaddress

while True:
    try:
        a = ipaddress.ip_address(input('Enter IP address: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(a)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Enter IP address: s
Enter IP address: a
Enter IP address: 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i managed to incorporate it into my code.
unfortunately i do not understand the try: function yet. but i will learn about it

Comment: @angpenghian `try..except` is how exceptions are handled in Python. If user enters invalid IP address, `ValueError` exception is thrown. More here for exemple: https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/

Comment: ahhh.. ok
to understand u correctly so ipaddress.ip_address is the one which verify if the ip address is proper.
and if it's proper the code will stop using the break
but if return valueerror it will continue the code.

thank you. learned something new. will understand the try function more

Comment: hello, i would like some help
i have changed your 'a' to 'wanip' 
but when i try to print(wanip) it says
Name 'wanip' can be undefined

is the a or wanip not a string or var?

Comment: @angpenghian Probably you're editing your code through some IDE and it complains that `wanip` is undefined. Put `wanip = None` at the beginning, to remove the warning.

Comment: yes i was using IDE, thank you i got it working

Answer (score 3):

There're multiple ways of doing it, if you want the simple one, based on [this guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html), you can use RegExp like this:

```
import re
check = re.match(r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$', YOUR_STRING)
if check:
    print('IP valid')
else:
    print('IP not valid')
```

In your situation it must look like:

```
wanip = str(input("please key in WAN IP address:"))
if not re.match(r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$', wanip):
    # Throw error here
# Continue with your code
```

If in loop:

```
import re

ip = None
while True:
    ip = str(input("please key in WAN IP address:"))
    if re.match(r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$', ip):
        # Say something to user
        break
    else:
        # Say something to user
        continue
print(ip)
```

Comment: thank you, your answer seems the easiest but im not familiar with Regex 
when i tried i get
"NameError: name 're' is not defined"
i looked at the guide it did not state what re should be.

Comment: Np, happens, I updated the answer :) `re` is the default library for Python, so you don't need to install anything else.

Comment: If there's any match - it's valid. If `None` - not valid.

Comment: thank you for the update. seems easier to understand now.
just need to figure out how to add into my code.
i understand it as it is. but my code requires to continue asking for next input instead of printing straight ;/

Comment: Updated it again a little bit :) If there's a bad IP, you need to stop processing and throw some error or smth, so the user could understand what's wrong. If IP is good - just continue asking below the code.

Comment: hello thank you for your update. i been playing around more on your code now
and i understand it already. but i have a new issue.
because Andrej Kesely codes allows me to loop back to the top if false
im trying to do that with yours with no luck.
i tired combing both yr code didnt work :(

Comment: :) Updated once again.

Comment: OMG, i was so close to your answer..
i googled. mine didnt work because the loop always define back input to 0
but why isit yours u put ip=none?

Comment: To initiate `ip` variable (to say Python we have it in "global" scope, and we're updating it and not creating it in the loop below). It's not required, just "better safe than sorry".

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
import ipaddress

try:
    user_ip = input("Enter adress: ")
    ip = ipaddress.ip_address(user_ip)
    print(f'{ip} is correct. Version: IPv{ip.version}')
except ValueError:
    print('Adress is invalid')
```

## Example of usage:

```
Enter adress: 23
Adress is invalid

Enter adress: 154.123.1.34
154.123.1.34 is correct. Version: IPv4
```

Comment: thank you for the answer yours seem similar to andrej's but i dont get the part.
print(f'{ip} is correct. Version: IPv{ip.version}')
as well as try.

i am only at Boolean Expression True and False on udemy. just doing this as a small project for myself

Comment: I recommend you reading this articles: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ , https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: thank you will check the links u suggested.
ah.. the f is the fstring. dam i need to practice more. it seems to be once of the basics

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
def validIPAddress(self, IP):
        
        def isIPv4(s):
            try: return str(int(s)) == s and 0 <= int(s) <= 255
            except: return False
            
        def isIPv6(s):
            if len(s) > 4: return False
            try: return int(s, 16) >= 0 and s[0] != '-'
            except: return False

        if IP.count(".") == 3 and all(isIPv4(i) for i in IP.split(".")): 
            return "IPv4"
        if IP.count(":") == 7 and all(isIPv6(i) for i in IP.split(":")): 
            return "IPv6"
        return "Neither"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i can see its similar to mateus as well.
but i do not know how to include it in my code with user input

Answer (score 1):

I think an even simpler solution would be to do this:

```
def isValid(ip):
    ip = ip.split(".")

    for number in ip:
        if not number.isnumeric() or int(number) > 255:
            return False
    
    return True
```

Even though using regex would probably be a better solution, I am not sure if you are already familiar with it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i can understand it as a stand alone. but i do not know how to add it into my code. :(

Comment: What do you mean? You can copy that function into your code and whenever you have to check if an ip is valid, you can use `if isValid(theIpYouWantToVerify): doSomething`.