# How to split string before and after certain characters?

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I have an assignment to create a python program that will receive an IP address and check if its valid or not, my problem is I dont know how to split the input so I will be able to check each octet whether its between 0 - 255 or not ?

Comment: You can use `string.split(".")`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure to post some of your own attempts at solving the problem.  Also, read documentation on ```string.split(separator, maxsplit)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the "split()" method.

```
ip = "192.68.10.10"

ip_arr = ip.split(".")

print(ip_arr)
```

This will return an array containing the 4 numbers:

`['192', '68', '10', '10']`

You can then loop through the array to check if each value is under 256. (Don't forget to convert to int before checking)

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse it. There's already a much more powerful library for that.
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319279/how-to-validate-ip-address-in-python) answer:

```
import socket

try:
    socket.inet_aton(addr)
    # legal
except socket.error:
    # Not legal
```