# how to limit input number using ReGex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex and I have a limit for input numbers, I want them to be less or equal to 255:

```
def validate(ip):
    try:
        x = re.search(r"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$", ip.strip())
        for pot in x.groups():
            if int(pot) <= 255:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    except:
         return False
validate('64.128.256.512')
```

well the problem is when I use a for loop, and using return, it checks only for one group of number (I mean the first one 64) and ignores the other, so the result will be True, but what I expect is False.

Comment: For those who don't know, `ReGex` is short for `Re'lar Gexpressions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is overkill here (for a non-robust method of validation) imo~

```
def validate(ip):
    split_ip = ip.split('.')
    return len(split_ip) == 4 and all(x <= 255 for x in map(int, split_ip))

>>> validate('64.128.256.512')
False
>>> validate('64.128.255.123')
True
>>> validate('64.128.255')
False
```

Comment: There's a ton that could be added, pos/negative, error catching for alpha characters, more specific ranges pertaining to IPs... etc. But at that point the tried and true regex methods available online from a simple search become better.

Answer (score 2):

Because `return` exits the function. You should first iterate through all the values and check to see if there is an invalid case. This can be done using `all()` like:

```py
import re

def validate(ip):
    x = re.search(r"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$", ip.strip())
    if not x:
        return False

    if all(int(pot) <= 255 for pot in x.groups()):
        return True
    return False

print(validate("64.128.256.512"))
print(validate("64.128.250.212"))
print(validate("foo.128.boo.212"))
```

output:

```
False
True
False
```

**Note1**: I guess it's an exercise, because [there are more robust ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319279/13944524) to validate IP addresses. I just fixed the problem you had.

**Note2**: Since you check for `\d` in your pattern, you don't need to add that try-except. If another non-digit value is provided, `search` will give you `None` and with the check `if not x:` you can simply return.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to validate an IP address using regex.

[This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-an-ip-address-using-regex/) covers that.

It suggests using this regex to validate an IPv4 address.
`"(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"`

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way i founded was:

```
def validate(ip):
    try:
        x = re.search(r"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$", ip.strip()) 
        n = 0
        for pot in x.groups():
            if int(pot) > 255:
                n += 1
        if n != 0:
            return False
        return True
    except:
        return False
```